# View variables in watch window in hex using WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ide, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2016.3 to write node.js code. During debugging, I would like to view a `Uint8Array[10]` variable using the watch window in hex. It is now shown in decimal.

How do I get WebStorm to display the variables in hex, and not decimal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option.

This is the best matching ticket I could find: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13942 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**P.S.**
There is mention of existing "View as | Hex" debugger functionality [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14933) but I'm not sure in what context/technology as it is not seem to be available for simple JavaScript debugging.

Comment: This is quite a basic feature. I am disappointed. Maybe I should go back to Visual Studio which has good Typescript support.